# Lost connection to iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, swift, connection, xcode6

I have recently start with development with `swift` with Xcode 6 beta 3.

I got Following error several times:
[image]

If i run again it runs, but many times this error occurs.

Is this Xcode bug or something?

[image: Screenshot for Xcode 6.1 stable-version]

Comment: Not tried in beta 4, need to download it.

Comment: This pops-up even in Xcode 6.1

Comment: I’ve found this happens with 6.1, but not 6.0.1.

Comment: Yes i also face this with 6.1.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is a bug, as you said just run again and it will be fine...

Remember this is a Beta...

Good Luck!

Comment: This is happen in 6.1 GM also.

Comment: you are correct, 6.1 also had many other bugs like sourcekit crashing all the time...  
btw it also happens in 6.1.1
it is still a bug but a very minor one, apple still has bigger things to deal with.